# How to replace text in file with unknown encoding using .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, io

I have many files contains some string. I want to replace this string with another value in all these files.

The files may have different encodings and extentions.

So, I'm using next method for all files

```
void ReplaceInFile(string file, string oldValue, string newValue)
{
 string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
 text = text.Replace(oldValue, newValue);
 File.WriteAllText(file, text);
}
```

But I'm not sure I will not broke some of them, which has some unusual encoding. Am I right?

What else I can use to do this operation for files with different encodings?

How can I check that nothing broken?

Comment: I assume this means you don't have any way of knowing/checking which encoding each specific file has?

Comment: It's simply not safe to change text when you don't know its encoding. If you read in a file with an unknown encoding, you may get an exception or some of the characters may be changed to other characters.

Comment: If you have the wrong encoding then it will probably not find the oldValue.  If it does not find the oldValue then don't save.  Even if you do find the oldValue that does not guarantee you have the correct encoding.

Comment: If there any way to get encoding somehow..? If no, then no, I don't know the encoding for file.

Comment: Sort of. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/17/2158334.aspx

Comment: Start with this: `new StreamReader(path, detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks=true);`. If that doesn't handle all files try the above suggestion. And read Spolsky on Unicode.

Comment: @groverboy the problem comes in when the file doesn't have a BOM, it just becomes a guessing game.

Answer (score 1):

You have to know the encoding of the file in order to interpret the data correctly.